# plotly map with inherit = FALSE in a layer

Tags: r, animation, plotly, r-sf

I'm using `plotly` to create a map with color-coded and animated points and an `sf` object. The points plot just fine on their own. The `sf` object also plots just fine. When I try to combine the animation color-coding with the `sf` object using `inherit = FALSE` option, the background map no longer plots. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Toy example:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
      select(AREA) %>%
       sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
       sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-76, -84, -2), y = seq(34, 36, 0.5)) %>%
      mutate(Group = sample(c("a", "b"), n(), replace = TRUE))

# plots points correctly, the animation works
plot_ly(df, lat = ~y, lon = ~x, color = ~Group, frame = ~Group,
    type = "scattermapbox", mode = 'markers') %>%
  layout(mapbox= list(style ="stamen-terrain", zoom = 4,
      center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35)))


# color-coding and animation work, and the sf object shows, but the map is gone
plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(data = df, y = ~y, x = ~x, color = ~Group, frame = ~Group,
    type = "scattermapbox", mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_sf(data = nc, x = ~x, y = ~y, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  layout(mapbox= list(style ="stamen-terrain", zoom = 4,
      center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your df into a sf object and use the CRS of your sf object. In the plot_ly call, you do not have to define lon/lat or x/y coords, because the coordinates are taken from the sf geometry column. Interestingly, 'stamen-terrain' didn't work for me, but 'open-street-map' does. Here is your code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  select(AREA) %>%
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")

head(nc)

# check crs
st_crs(nc)

df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-76, -84, -2), y = seq(34, 36, 0.5)) %>%
  mutate(Group = sample(c("a", "b"), n(), replace = TRUE))

# convert df to sf object and set crs
df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4267)
head(df)

# color-coding and animation work, and the sf object shows, but the map is gone -> now it works
plot_ly() %>%
  add_sf(data = df, 
              color = ~Group, 
              frame = ~Group,
              type = "scattermapbox", 
              mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_sf(data = nc, 
         type = "scattermapbox", 
         mode = 'lines',
         inherit = FALSE) %>%
  layout(mapbox= list(style ="open-street-map", 
                      zoom = 4,
                      center = list(lon = -80 ,lat= 35)))

plot_ly
```