# R flexdashboard animation with 2 traces has issue with animation slider

Tags: r, animation, plotly, flexdashboard

This question is an extension to the question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76862268/r-plot-ly-animation-with-2-traces-has-issue-with-animation-slider/76863754?noredirect=1#comment135542795_76863754), where an animation with a factor level on the x-axis and the same factor level as the frame in the animation have the order of the factor messed up on the slider. The question was answered for `plotly` in general. However, in the `flexdashboard`, I'm using shared data, and the answer provided in the original question doesn't cover that scenario (because it wasn't mentioned in the original question). Any help would be appreciated!

Toy example (Rmd code):

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
 ---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(crosstalk)     
library(flexdashboard) 
library(dplyr)         
library(plotly)    

# Make up data
data <- expand.grid(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-04-01"), by = "1 day"),
                    Group = c("A", "B")) %>%  
            mutate(N = rnorm(n(), 0, 1),
                fr = format(Date, "%d-%b"),
                fr = factor(fr, levels = unique(fr)))

# Shared data
S_data <- SharedData$new(data, ~Group, group = "Group")
```

Date animation
===================================== 
 Column 1 {data-width=80}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Data selection
```{r}
  filter_select(id = "group", label = "group",
    sharedData = S_data, group = ~Group, multiple = FALSE)
```

Column 2 {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
## function provided in the answer linked to the original question
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)                   # build to get data
                                             # capture current animation order in plot
  curOrd <- invisible(lapply(1:length(plt$x$frames), function(j) {
    plt$x$frames[[j]]$name
  })) %>% unlist()
  
  fixOrd <- match(levels(data$fr), curOrd)    # compare current order; get index to fix
  plt$x$frames <- plt$x$frames[fixOrd]       # rearrange frames & slider (steps)
  plt$x$layout$sliders[[1]]$steps <- plt$x$layout$sliders[[1]]$steps[fixOrd]

                                       # change the base anim frame (when not animating)
  plt$x$data[[2]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[1]]
  plt # return plot
}

fig <- plot_ly(S_data) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N, color = ~Group, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers") %>%
   add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N,
            frame = ~fr, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            marker = list(color = "fuchsia")) %>%
  animation_slider() %>% fixer()  
fig
```
````

**EDIT**

Took me a minute to figure out how to upload videos, but here's 2 recordings. I commented out the `fixer` portion, so that there's less to troubleshoot.

Video 1 - the plot is colour-coded. The selection works correctly on the static points, but the animated traces are no longer animated.

[image: Video 1]

Video 2 - the plot isn't colour-coded. The selection works correctly on the static points, and the animated trace is animated, but there are still 2 animated points, whereas there should only be 1 per selected group.

[image: Video 2]

Comment: When you added `color = ~Group`, `plt$x$data[[2]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[1]]` became a problem. You can use the legend for this particular plot. Now that you have an  A and a B, the animation trace for the first frame is now in the third trace (the first trace was split into two traces, one for each color--specifically when working with discrete colors). If you change this to `plt$x$data[[3]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[1]]` you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm. Not quite - with the correction you suggested I'm getting the colour separation and the order of the slider correctly. However, if I select a group in the select filter, the animated trace no longer works (with or without the `fixer` function). But the trace is animated as long as I don't select a group...  I seem to be not understanding something very basic about how the animation works in `plotly`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying you can't animate at all if you select a group? It animates for me. If you select a group, your animation shouldn't change. Did you mean that the animation doesn't do what you expected, something like only animating one of the groups?

Comment: I added 2 videos and a description of the issue. I hope that works? Just to recap - if the groups are colour-coded in the plot, the animated trace isn't animated. If the groups aren't colour-coded, the animated trace works, but there are 2 animated points instead of one, despite using the shared data in the plot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

I won't rehash the items I mentioned before this update.

The only changes are in the `onRender` function. I've added another UDF within it that loops through the frames to change the visibility, whether you're on 'A' or 'B'. The results of this function replace the frames in `aData` and `bData` respectively. Let me know if you have any questions after you look at the code comments.

Here's the updated call to create `fig`.

```
fig <- plot_ly(S_data) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N, color = ~Group, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers") %>%
   add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N,
            frame = ~fr, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            split = ~Group, showlegend = F,
            marker = list(color = "fuchsia")) %>%
  animation_slider() %>% fixer() %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {     /* working within HTMLwidgets */
      sel = document.querySelector('select');     /* get sel and container els*/
      dbc = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
      xx = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));   /* create deep copy of original data */
      visAdj = function(grp, dt) {          /* function for creating group data  */
        dt.data.forEach(function(elem, i) { /* if trace name == group name */
          if (dt.data[i].name === grp) {dt.data[i].visible = true} 
          if (dt.data[i].name !== grp) {dt.data[i].visible = false}
        })
        return(dt);                         /* rtn dataset */
      };
      ffBld = function(grp, dt) {           /* for creating grouped frame data */
        dt.forEach(function(it, ind) {          /* through each frame */
          it.data.forEach(function(dit, dind) { /* each trace within each frame */
            if(dit.name === grp) {dit.visible = true}  /* change vis by group */
            if(dit.name !== grp) {dit.visible = false}
          })
        })
        return(dt);                         /* rtn frames */
      }
      aData = visAdj('A', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx))); /* create GROUP data*/
      aData.frames = ffBld('A', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx.frames)));
      bData = visAdj('B', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx)));
      bData.frames = ffBld('B', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx.frames)));
    
      selv = sel.value;                        /* establish initial value */
      setInterval(function() {  /* monitor for changes; onChange ev not poss */
        sv = sel.value;            /* what is selected? is it different? */
        if(selv !== sv) {
          tellMe(sv);
          selv = sv;                       /* reset selv for next change */
        }
      }, 1000);                                   /* millisec btw checks */

      tellMe = function(selO) {         /* what do I do if there is a change? */
        if(selO === '' || selO === '(All)') {              /* show all data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, xx);
        } else if (selO === 'A') {                         /* show A data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, aData);
        } else if (selO === 'B') {                         /* show B data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, bData);
        }
      };
    }")
```

---

---

#### Original Answer

There are a few things that are happening here.

1. I've added `split` to the trace with frames - this helps to absolve the issues that `crosstalk` creates between `sharedData` and animation frames.
2. Instead of one line for the first animation frame, there are two (due to the split). (This is the 2nd last line, now the 2nd and 3rd last line of code in the fixer function.)
3. I've added an `onRender` function. I wasn't able to determine if it would have been easier to add a button with JS, instead of `crosstalk`, or not. In this version, you're going to keep the dropdown as you've written it. The `onRender` function changes what data you see when you select a specific group.

Within the `onRender`, I've written a lot of comments so that you could see what does what. If you were to use different data, you would need to adjust the lines of code that create the objects `aData`, `bData` and the function  called `tellMe` (within `onRender`, at the end). Since there were only two groups in this data, I didn't do a loop or anything particularly dynamic.

If you have any questions after you look through this code, let me know.

First, the `fixer()` function. I kept the original line in the code but commented it out.

```
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)                   # build to get data
                                             # capture current animation order in plot
  curOrd <- invisible(lapply(1:length(plt$x$frames), function(j) {
    plt$x$frames[[j]]$name
  })) %>% unlist()
  
  fixOrd <- match(levels(data$fr), curOrd)    # compare current order; get index to fix
  plt$x$frames <- plt$x$frames[fixOrd]       # rearrange frames & slider (steps)
  plt$x$layout$sliders[[1]]$steps <- plt$x$layout$sliders[[1]]$steps[fixOrd]

                                       # change the base anim frame (when not animating)
  # plt$x$data[[3]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[1]]

  plt$x$data[[3]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[1]] # need two because of the split
  plt$x$data[[4]] <- plt$x$frames[[1]]$data[[2]]
    # anim Frame fxr prep
  plt # return plot
}
```

The plot with the `onRender` function.

```
fig <- plot_ly(S_data) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N, color = ~Group, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers") %>%
   add_trace(x = ~fr,
            y = ~N,
            frame = ~fr, 
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            split = ~Group, showlegend = F,
            marker = list(color = "fuchsia")) %>%
  animation_slider() %>% fixer() %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {     /* working within HTMLwidgets */
      sel = document.querySelector('select');     /* get sel and container els*/
      dbc = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
      xx = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));   /* create deep copy of original data */
      visAdj = function(grp, dt) {          /* function for creating group data  */
        dt.data.forEach(function(elem, i) {
          if (dt.data[i].name === grp) {    /* if trace name == group name */
            dt.data[i].visible = true;
          } else {
            dt.data[i].visible = false;
          }
        });
        return(dt);                         /* rtn dataset */
      };
      aData = visAdj('A', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx))); /* create GROUP data*/
      bData = visAdj('B', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx)));

      selv = sel.value;                        /* establish initial value */
      setInterval(function() {  /* monitor for changes; onChange ev not poss */
        sv = sel.value;            /* what is selected? is it different? */
        if(selv !== sv) {
          tellMe(sv);
          selv = sv;                       /* reset selv for next change */
        }
      }, 1000);                                   /* millisec btw checks */

      tellMe = function(selO) {         /* what do I do if there is a change? */
        if(selO === '' || selO === '(All)') {              /* show all data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, xx);
        } else if (selO === 'A') {                         /* show A data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, aData);
        } else if (selO === 'B') {                         /* show B data */
          Plotly.newPlot(el.id, bData);
        }
      };
    }")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the super-slow response time here. Aside from how amazing you are and how much time/thought went into the answer - any chance you could look at why there are 2 animated points in your answer, as opposed to the single point that should be animated per group?

Comment: Your animation data was never divided into groups. The animation can be split, but it wasn't something I considered when I put my answer together. Is that something you wanted to see?

Comment: Then maybe I'm completely misunderstanding. I _thought_ (obviously, migsuided?) that by using the shared data, I was a-priori only animating the one, selected, group subset. And I would LOVE to see that!

Comment: I've modified my answer with an update that should give you what you're looking for. Let me know if you have any questions.